# What is the Magma Crystal used for in Boom Beach?

Tags: boom-beach

I received a gift from a boat that offered me stone wood or this magma crystal, curiosity got the best of me and I got this crystal but now I cannot find it in my inventory so what does it do or what is it used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fragments, Shards, and Crystals can be turned into Statues of the same element (Life, Ice, Magma, or Dark) at the Sculptor.

However, it takes 7 of the same element and grade of these to create a Statue.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for that I haven't built the sculptor yet, I may have to do so :)